# One Testrail test case Id linked to more than one test suites

Tags: testrail

I have two Testrail test suites in TestRail: "manual" and "automation". We have a test automation process that sends the results to testrail. That process targets the "automation" test suite, so every time we need to create a new test case the manual test team creates one in the "manual" test suite and the automation test team creates the same test case in the "automation" test suite. Instead of duplicating test cases between the "manual" and "automation" test suites I would like to use the same test case ID in both of them, if that's possible.

Note: *it might seem obvious that I should only use one test suite for both manual and automation and eventually I will be able to do but I can't do it now, so I need a quicker solution*

I have not been able to find an option in Testrail to do that

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible. Each test case has a `suite_id` field which contains an ID of the corresponding suite. So you cannot actually add the same test case into several suites or sections.

Maybe it's better to send results for cases from 'manual' suite, but use some different plan name or some custom result field to distinguish it.

By the way, we are developing a product called [Railflow](https://railflow.io) which helps to integrate almost any testing automation framework with TestRail without any coding. Maybe you might want to have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is a good a idea. Sure I will take a look at Railflow, thank you for bringing it up. I’m sorry I don’t enough reputation to vote for your answer.